# Analysing a context-free grammar

Tags: formal-grammars

Let:

$$S \to AC \mid BC\\
A \to aAb \mid aA \mid a\\
B \to aBb \mid Bb \mid b\\
C \to Cc \mid c$$

I need to find if:

1. the word $aabbbcc $ is in the grammer, and if so to write a very left series, and the tree.
2. what is the languege that the grammer creates?
3. to tell if the grammer is ambiguous

---

**My try:**

1. Yes, $aabbbcc$ is in the grammer because $S\Longrightarrow BC\Longrightarrow aBbC \Longrightarrow aaBbbC\Longrightarrow aabbbC\Longrightarrow aabbbCc \Longrightarrow aabbbcc$

   [image]
2. The laguage is $\mathscr{L}=\{a^*b^*c^*\}$
3. I think that the grammer is not ambiguous because I didn't find a word $x\in \mathscr{L}$ such that there are two series to $x$

I'm not sure if my attempt is correct or not.

Comment: 1) Please don't dump huge formulae in titles. 2) It's gramm**a**r. 3) Words are not in grammars, but in languages generated by grammars. 4) The language is wrong. Note that there can not be as many $a$'s as $b$'s. 5) "I can not find such $x$" is not a proof. 6) There is no *question* here. Answer-checking is not something we like to do. Please make sure to include a specific question about your attempt or the problem. (Community votes, please: is this "unclear"?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33527/discussion-between-nehorai-and-raphael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation is correct. The language is not (your answer allows the empty word to be part of the language for example). For the third question: did you exhaust every word in the language ? Is the language finite ?

Try again.

Answer (score 0):

The derivation is indeed correct.

The language is not ambiguous, I've gone through a bunch of expressions myself trying to prove otherwise to no avail.

As for the language the grammar creates, I think that it is (a|b)(a*|b*)(c*|c) and my reasons for this is that the grammar:

1.must, at least, include a combination of a, b, c, the empty word is not allowed.

2.must start with either the letter a OR the letter b

Comment: "I went through a bunch of derivations without finding an ambguity" doesn't prove anything. Determining if a grammar is ambiguous is undecidable in general.

Comment: @vonbrand Undecidability does not mean unprovability. (But it *does* debunk every algorithmic approach.)